# How to use Eigen's unaryExpr with custom scalar type?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I have the following code:

```
Matrix<Vector3f, 3, 3> m;
m(0,0) = Vector3f(0,0,0);
m(1,0) = Vector3f(1,1,1);
m(2,0) = Vector3f(2,2,2);
m(0,1) = Vector3f(3,3,3);
m(1,1) = Vector3f(4,4,4);
m(2,1) = Vector3f(5,5,5);
m(0,2) = Vector3f(6,6,6);
m(1,2) = Vector3f(7,7,7);
m(2,2) = Vector3f(8,8,8);

auto lambda = [&](const Ref<const Vector3f> & element)->Vector3f{ return element * -1;};
auto b = m.unaryExpr(lambda);
cout << b << endl;
```

But this code won't compile. So I am wondering if that is possible to use unaryExpr with custom scalar type? If yes, is there an example?

The compiling error:

> /path/Eigen/src/Core/IO.h:132:95: error: no matching function for call
>   to
>   ‘log(Eigen::internal::significant_decimals_default_impl, false>::RealScalar)’
>        return cast(ceil(-log(NumTraits::epsilon())/log(RealScalar(10))));

Comment: What do mean by wont compile?  What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: @NathanOliver I just updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unaryExpr` works fine (though it would have been simpler to use a `const Vector3f & element` as argument).

What is not working is `cout << b << endl;` because Eigen tries to call `log` and `ceil` on a `Vector3f` to format the output.

Comment: Thank you. And is that possible to return a different scalar type with unaryExpr? For example I have a 'Vector3f' type of return value in the above code, so is it OK to return a bool type with reduction functions? Cause when I trying to do so, i got 'could not convert  blah blah return derived().functor()(derived().nestedExpression().coeff(rowId, colId));' error